# Prove that the set is close

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, continuity, metric-spaces, automated-theorem-proving

Given metric spaces $(X,d)$ and $(Y,d')$ and continuous mapping $S$ and $T$ from $X$ into $Y$, prove that the set $\{x \in X: Sx = Tx\}$ is closed in $(X,d)$.

I've run out of any ideas where I should start

Comment: How about you pick a convergent sequence from your set and show that it has to converge to an element of the set?

Comment: Take a point $x$ where $Sx \not= Tx$ and show that  $Sy \not= Ty$ for all $y$ in some neighborhood of $x$. This will mean that the set $\{x : Sx \not= Tx\}$ is *open*.

Answer (score 1):

Let $E=\{x∈X:Sx=Tx\}$. Suppose $x_n \in E$ and $x_n \to x$.

By continuity, $S x_n \to Sx$ and $T x_n \to Tx$. But $Sx_n=Tx_n$ for all $n\ge1$, hence, $Sx=Tx$ and this means $x\in E$. This implies $E=\{x∈X:Sx=Tx\}$ is closed.

Answer (score 0):

You can give a topological proof as follows:

Consider the function $D:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $D(x)=d(S(x),T(x))$. Since $S$ and $T$ are continuous and the distance function $d$ is continuous, then $D$ is continuous, so given $F$ a closed subset in $\mathbb{R}$ we have that:
$$D^{-1}(F)=\{x\in X:D(x)\in F\}$$
is a closed subset in $X$.

We also know that in a metric space, the points are closed. In particular, $\{0\}$ is a closed set in $\mathbb{R}$.

And we have finished, because:
$$\{x\in X: S(x)=T(x)\}=D^{-1}(\{0\})$$
which is closed.

Comment: $Y$ needn't be a topological group. The *differenence* $S-T$ thus does not have a meaning. For $Y=\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$ this argument is correct.

Comment: You are right. I modified the argument, changing $S-T$ by the distance between $S$ and $T$ in each point.